# How to resolve “Validation (): Element ‘x’ is not supported” warning in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have been getting all of these "Validation (): Element 'x' is not supported" warnings and I can't seem to find a way to get rid of them. Here are two examples:

- Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Attribute 'name' is not a valid attribute of element 'ul'.
- Validation (CSS 2.1): 'border-radius' is not a known CSS property name.

I have searched on the web and all solutions point to removing the following folder:

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming \Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ReflectedSchemas
```

Which seems to fix 90% of people's issues, however I don't have that folder anywhere on my computer!

I am using Visual Studio 10 SP1 and this project is an MVC 3 project using Razor and HTML5.

So can anyone else suggest what else might be causing the issue?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are valid warnings, not a bug or other sort of "issue." The list of valid attributes for `<ul>` is given in [the W3C standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2), and it doesn't include `name`. Meanwhile, `border-radius` was introduced in CSS 3, which means if you validate against CSS 2.1 it's not going to work.

You can either ignore them or figure out how to suppress those particular warnings in VS2010 (I know how to do that for VC++, but I haven't used VS for HTML before; there should be some section in the Properties window for it).

Comment: How do i change the version which my project validates against? I have found how to hide the warnings, but i would like to fix them. Thanks very much.

Comment: @AlexTyman: Well, you're not going to be able to "fix" the name error -- `name` is not a valid attribute for `<ul>` in any version of HTML. You will have to change your HTML if you want that one to go away. For validating the CSS, that's a different question I don't know the answer to. I'm sure Google has that answer, though.

Comment: I probably chose a bad example then in that case! Thanks, and i'll search for the validation answer.

Answer (score 9):

I was encountering the same problem and ALL classic html elements (div, a, p, table..) in every page had green underlines. Intellisense did not give any help with these elements, as if they didn't exist. But all asp controls were fine and valid.

[image: Green underlines]

The error was the `xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` in the `html` tag in my master page. Html 5 does not seem to work well together with the `xmlns` declaration so I removed it, and voila - everything magically works again!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to know it's not an error!

Steps to resolve the warning message for an element.

1. Right click the warning area, you will see a context menu.
2. Click "Formatting and Validation..." basically it's at the bottom of the menu.
3. Go to "Validation" in "HTML or HTML (Web Forms)" section. You'll see a checkbox with "Show errors" is checked to true with header "Options". Just unchecke it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNp6O.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nacQu.png)

That's it, you are done...

Comment: Please could you edit your answer and fill in the image descriptions?

Comment: Okay follow these steps in your visual studio go to:

1. Tools > Options > Text Editor> HTML (Web Forms) > Validation
2. Now uncheck "Show errors"

That's it...

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove

```
xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
```

let it remain

```
<!DocType Html>
```

only above